# Deleted answer can be flagged for moderator's attention

Tags: discussion, support, flags, moderation

I have opened a question and after sometime an answer was posted. But, since the answer was a link only answer I was trying to flag it for moderators attention. So when I clicked flag the popup appears with the following option only,

> Other (needs ♦ moderator attention) This question needs a moderator's
>   attention. Please describe exactly what's wrong.

And after flagging, when I checked the post, it was deleted before I flagged the answer. So, my question is, if all other options for flagging are removed when the post was deleted, why does this one remain?

[This is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950447/how-to-use-angular-js-in-laravel/24950544#24950544) which contains the answer I flagged.

Answer (score 4):

The other four flag reasons (if the flag is correct) generally result in the answer getting deleted. There's no point in flagging already deleted answers with those reasons.

Now, you can still flag for moderator attention when there's something really wrong with the answer. An example I can think of is when it contains information that should be nuked so even 10k+ users can't see it.